# Understanding circuit : Output of a CD4017 with 1N4148 diode and RC circuit

Tags: digital-logic, parallel, remote-control, output

I'm reading a circuit on a magazine (look at circuit below) and i don't understand , why the author put a 1N4148 diode and a RC circuit at the output of CD4017 , what is the operations of the RC circuit , and why do we need a diode here.

Can someone explain to me that

Thanks in advance for your replies

[image: Output of a CD4017]

Answer (score 2):

Part of this has already been answered on your previous question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116661/debouncing-parallel-rc-circuit). As for the diode, that is very important if you consider what happens when the capacitor is fully charged by the 4017 - if the relevant output of the 4017 goes low, it won't discharge the capacitor - the cap will discharge only at the rate caused by the 10k resistor. If the diode were a short, as soon as the 4017 output went low it would immediately (10us or so) discharge the capacitor.

There are other things about the diodes used as well - any of the four outputs can charge the capacitor so, in effect the four diodes are acting like a 4-input-OR gate.

Comment: Tx andy , sorry for being that persistent but i'm not fuly understanding circuit operations, the output of 4017 is set for 65 seconds , don't see why it wil be necessary to put a cap and a resistor here as well as a diode (what is a short) , if i don't put this on the circuit what will be the consequences.

Comment: It's not how long the signal is set for; it's what happens when the signal clears - the RC circuit keeps the voltage at a logic 1 for a few milli seconds after the 4017 clears down. A short is a short circuit i.e. replacing the diode with a wire.

Comment: French speaking & quite new to electronics , sorry making things difficult to you , so the author just want to keep the logic 1 for few milli seconds after the output of 4017 goes down , it's disturbing for me because there is defined time cycles can't see why it's relevant for the circuit operations, but you can't guess i'm just exposing a sample, let me check few things... , appreciate your invaluable help

Comment: @Blu3sy I can't see any other reason but I don't have the full circuit.

Answer (score 1):

RC circuit (R9-C9) is  a debounce circuit, that's all , because there 4 switches which may produce unwanted pulses  which coud trigger the input of the transistor T1 . We need to protect the four diodes to protect the circuit 4017 beause of the discharge of the C9.

Comment: Sorry I should say  we need the four diodes to protect the circuit 4017 because of the discharge of the C9.

Comment: You can edit your answer pressing the *edit* link below your answer. After editing, you can delete the comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Appears as if the purpose of including the RC (assuming `R9` and `C9` here) configuration is to drive the transistor `T1`. The output fo the 4017 will charge `C9` and provide base current to drive the transistor.

The RC filter will provide a delay for how long the transistor stays active after the 4017 has stopped charging the capacitor (i.e. input LOW or high-impedance). The consequence of not including `C9` and `R9` would be that the transistor turns off immediately when the controller stops driving it.

The purpose of the diode is exactly as Andy has said above.

Comment: Tx for your help , so maybe the current provided by the 4017 output is not enough to drive the transistor , and what will explain the RC circuit here, i think it's possible to use capacitor to somehow increase the amperage .

Comment: Not at all. The output of the 4017 both driver the transistor *and* charges the capacitor for some time. Once the capacitor is full charged then the 4017 drives only the transistor. Once the 4017 is switched off the diode protects the capacitor discharge back into the 4017 pins, so it beings to discharge through `R9` and `R10` since there is nothing holding its potential any longer (as the 4017 *was*).

Comment: The capacitor is a passive component, it doesn't *produce* anything. I think what you mean, or perhaps the context through which you have read about, capacitors *supplying* current is when they are implemented as decoupling capacitors. In this way, when a digital circuit is switching and requires pulses of current, such supplement current cannot pass through the trace inductances quick enough to supply the IC. Therefore, the charged capacitors supply this current and are then recharged at a slower rate by the main supply.

Comment: Thanks for clarification , i know that decoupling capacitors are here to respond to the changes of current without disturbing circuit operations.

Actually i was referring to an article that i just found 

http://www.ehow.com/how_8780713_increase-amperage-capacitors-diodes.html

Comment: Everything about that link is terribly inaccurate - please don't go back there. With references like "connect AC through a diode and observe DC current", I would never visit there again. Just read up on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) and try [this](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/capacitor.htm) site. I can't verify the latter but it's generally good quality.

Comment: ehow - how to burn your house quickly i guess , i'll take the advice seriously , trying to dig more to finish reading the circuit comments , the circuit is 5 pages long  maybe i'll get a clue somewhere.

Comment: [This](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_1/3.html) is also a wonderful resource.